# No output shown after reading a .txt file using Pandas in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using python version 3.6.3 and installed pandas recently.

I have created a file test.txt. 2 columns (tab separated). File & code is saved in the same directory.

```
1   Samsung
2   Nokia
3   iPhone
```

When I run the code the output is blank (no error/warning). What did I do wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('test.txt', 
                    sep='\t', 
                    header=None, 
                    names=["Sl.", "Name"])
df.head()
```

Comment: The code works fine for me. Do you also try `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: Same result. 1 query though (as a newbie in programming world). While I run this code from cmd, there is no output. But when I enter Python from cmd & then run the code, it gives right output. Should this always be the case, as for other python files I just run from cmd w/o entering into Python

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "entering Python"? You mean typing line by line in the python console?

Comment: Yes, while I type in python console the code is working fine. But while I run the code(saved in testing.py file) cmd it gives blank output.

Comment: Do you mean there is no output when you run `python testing.py` in cmd? If it is the case, add `print(df.head())` at the end of your .py file.

Comment: When running in a script you need to explicitly print it out. like

Comment: Thanks, @kitman0804 this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to print it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('a.txt',
                sep='\t',
                header=None,
                names=["Sl.", "Name"])
print('The dataframe is {}'.format(df.head()))
```